# django runserver start downlonding file containing this string <function render at 0x0000023B61F4F160>

Tags: python, html, django, render

After running: py manage.py runserver
instead of showing me the html views, this string is shown on the page:

<function render at 0x0000023B61F4F160>

after few minutes this message appears on the terminal:

[13/Nov/2020 08:39:05] "GET /socketcluster/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2129

Answer (score 0):

wrong sintax

solution:
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

## Create your views here.

def index (request):

```
return render (request, 'homepage/index.html')
```

before I wrote return HtppResponse(render, 'homepage/index.html')